# Possible to mock function such that one parameter is always set to a specified value?

Tags: python, python-mock

For example, suppose I have the function:

```
def foo(var1, var2):
    print '%s, %s' % (var1, var2)
```

Is it possible using Mock or another tool to temporarily override the function such that the second value is always set to some value, like `lorem ipsum`?

```
foo('hello', 'world') # prints "hello, lorem ipsum"
foo('goonight', 'moon') # prints "goodnight, lorem ipsum"
```

I would still need to change foo() even when it's nested in another function/class:

```
def greet(name):
    foo('hello', name)


greet('john') # prints "hello, lorem ipsum"
```

This is intended to be used as a way to force a consistent action when unit testing. Seems like a simple problem, but haven't managed to find a good option yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Save a reference to the original function, then patch it with a function that calls the original with the fixed second argument.

```
original_foo = foo  
# Or whatever name actually needs to be patched 
with mock.patch('__main__.foo', lambda x, y: original_foo(x, 'lorem ipsum')):
    # do stuff involving foo
```

The important thing is that the patched object cannot refer to `foo` directly, since the lookup of the name `foo` would occur in the context where the name `foo` has already been patched, leading to an infinite loop.